# Firebase image upload completes with success but image is not in firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, upload, firebase-storage

I have this code that uploads an image that is taken with the camera or obtained from the photo library. The upload happens and succeeds after this code executes:

```
// Return a promise to catch errors while loading image
  getMedia(options, square, username): Promise<any> {
    //this.storage.get('username').then((val) => {this.username = val; console.log(this.username + "        getting usern34433245555555ame")});

    // Get Image from ionic-native's built in camera plugin
    return this.camera.getPicture(options)
      .then((fileUri) => {

        // op Image, on android this returns something like, '/storage/emulated/0/Android/...'
        // Only giving an android example as ionic-native camera has built in cropping ability
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {

          return this.crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 10 });
        } else if (this.platform.is('android')) {
          // Modify fileUri format, may not always be necessary
          fileUri = 'file://' + fileUri;

          /* Using cordova-plugin-crop starts here */
          return this.crop.crop(fileUri, { quality: 10 });
        }
      })
      .then(newPath => {
        console.log(newPath);
        if(newPath) {
          let fileName = newPath.substring(newPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, newPath.length);
          let filePath = newPath.substring(0, newPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
          this.file.readAsDataURL(filePath, fileName).then(data => {
            //let strImage = data.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");
            //this.file.writeFile(this.file.tempDirectory, "image.jpg", strImage);
            //let blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
            var dataURL = data;

            console.log(username + "    this is passed usernameeeeeeeeee    ==");

              let image       : string  = 'profilepicture.png',
              storageRef  : any,
              parseUpload : any;

              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                storageRef       = firebase.storage().ref('/profile/' + username + '/' + image);
                parseUpload      = storageRef.putString(dataURL, 'data_url');

                console.log(username + "     username in promise  !!!!!!");

                console.log("got to storageref after");
                parseUpload.on('state_changed', (_snapshot) => {
                    // We could log the progress here IF necessary
                    console.log('snapshot progess ' + _snapshot);
                  },
                  (_err) => {
                     reject(_err);
                     console.log(_err.messsage);
                  },
                  (success) => {
                    console.log(' was     a      suc    cesssssss');
                     resolve(parseUpload.snapshot); 
                  })
                }).then(value => {
                  //this.af.list('/profile/' + self.username).push({ pic: image });
                }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error.message);
                });

            //let file
           });
          }
        });

  }
```

The console output for `console.log(username + "     username in promise  !!!!!!");` is correct and I believe the correct `storageRef` is being used.

The console output for the upload is this:

```
[20:35:56]  console.log: Blue username in promise !!!!!! 
[20:35:56]  console.log: got to storageref after 
[20:35:56]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[20:35:57]  console.log: snapshot progess [object Object] 
[20:35:57]  console.log: was a suc cesssssss
```

However, when I look at firebase storage, the new folder and image are not there. There are no changes to firebase storage. Why isn't it actually storing in the storage?

Answer (score 0):

`storageRef       = firebase.storage().ref('/profile/' + username + '/' + image);`

was supposed to be:

`storageRef       = firebase.storage().ref('/settings/' + username + '/' + image);`

I was looking for the upload in the wrong folder.